# Check if Phonegap app is running on iPad or iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I would like to check inside my javascript file if I am running on an iPad or an iPhone. My app was using previously the device.platform method of Phonegap 1.9 which was retrieving "iPhone" or "iPad". I am now upgrading the app to Phonegap 3.0 and this same method retrieves "iOS".

Is there a clean method to retrieve the platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you use device.name method

Comment: device.name is deprecated as of version 2.3.0. I will use device.model instead. Thanks for good direction.